# Geoserver on Tomcat - FAIL - Application at context path /geoserver could not be started. [WEB-INF] is not Valid

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, geoserver

I'm running tomcat 8-RC10 and (attempting) geoserver 2.4.3 deployed from .war.
Geoserver won't start with the above error, and the catalina.out (which is so long and detailed as to be almost useless) seems to have trouble at the point:

`ERROR [context.ContextLoader] - context initialization failed`

`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'geoServerLoader' defined in URL [jar:file:/home/XXX/tomcat/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/main-2.2.4.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'resourceLoader' while setting constructor argument;`

`nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceLoader' defined in URL [jar:file:/home/XXX/tomcat/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/main-2.2.4.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: initialization of bean failed;`

`nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The resource path [WEB-INF] is not valid.`

Appreciate any suggestions, I'm quite clearly in over my head here.

Comment: Is there a more complete stack trace? Does WEB-INF exist?

Comment: There is a **very** complete stack trace, I'll upload it later today if I can. WEB-INF definitely exists, it was created as part of unpacking the geoserver.war.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else runs into this, it seems that tomcat 8 is not supported by geoserver as yet. My recommendation is downloading and unzipping tomcat7 from the .tar, according the instructions at : http://diegobenna.blogspot.com.au/2011/01/install-tomcat-7-in-ubuntu-1010.html

Answer (score 0):

One of your beans references a bean named 'resourceloader' but there is no bean with that name in your application context as indicated by the message:

`cannot resolve reference to bean 'resourceloader`

Comment: Hmm... That could be right, I suspect that 'resourceLoader' couldn't be created because of the resource path [WEB-INF] error. I don't know why this would happen though, because I haven't written any beans myself, they are all created by one of the two packages.

Comment: Is there anything you've annotated with that name?

Comment: Nope, all I did was install and run :/ I thought it could be a permissions thing, but I've changed all the permissions and still no better.